# No code inside of my for loop is being run - Java 8 SE

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8

I've been working on a simple Java code where you are to give 5 numbers to the program through the console, which will then tell you what numbers you chose and give you an average. I noticed, however, after I started trying to test my code, that the for loop was basically 'skipping over' all of the code inside of the loop, and I have no idea why. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class numAv {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num;
    int[] numbers = new int[5];
    boolean done = false;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Enter five integer numbers one at a time.");
    for (int i = 0; i >= 5; i++) {
        scan.nextLine();
        num = scan.nextInt();

        numbers[i] = num;
    }
    // The code inside the for loop is being skipped; I'm not getting any time to type in an integer.

    System.out.println("Your numbers are:");

    for (int i = 0; i >= 5; i++) {

        System.out.print(numbers[i]);
    }
    // The same has also happened above; The code within the for loop is essentially being skipped.

    num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i >= 5; i++) {
        num += numbers[i];
    }
    num /= (float) 5;
    System.out.println("The average of the chosen numbers is " + num);
}

}
```

Here's what the console outputs:

```
Enter five integer numbers one at a time.
Your numbers are:
The average of the chosen numbers is: 0
```

Comment: Sorry, But can you explain what will equation evaluate when you type i>=5 on _for (int i = 0; i >= 5; i++) _ ?
because as far as I know when you write i>=5 which means 0>=5.

Comment: if you use this  i <= 5  experssion when Runtime throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException. if you used this i < 5 expression it fine.

Comment: just to be specific, the condition (2nd expression) in the `for` statement must evaluate to `true` for the loop block to be executed (that is, it is not the condition to terminate but the one to loop). The condition is also checked before the first iteration.

Comment: Unrelated: please learn about java naming conventions. Class names should go UpperCase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad condition:

```
for (int i = 0; i >= 5; i++) {
```

This will never works, try this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
```

Comment: Thanks. I always get that one part messed up, where it's essentially as long as the number is bigger than i, the for loop will run.

Comment: @cowbears101 Try to mentally read the loop as "for i starts at 0 and is greater than or equal to 5, incrementing i".

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
for (int i = 0; i >= 5; i++) {
```

`i` will have a really hard time being zero and bigger than 5 at the same time.

The real answer here: each and any character that you put into your source code matters. There is a big difference between `<=` and `>=`, and even between `<=` and `<` for that matter. So, when your code doesn't do what you expect it to do: take a piece of paper, and start "running" that code manually. Really write down the values within your variables, and carefully check what the code is doing with them.